# Colour the background of a card based on the card content - why is it skipping the first card?

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to change the background colour of the card based on the content but it skipping the first card/div. How do I prevent the first card from being skipped when setting the background colour?
[Blazor Fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aizJk.png)

```
@foreach (TimeLog time in timeList)
{
    <div class="largeCard" id="cardstyle" style="background-color: @cardColour ">
        <div>
            @if (time.LogType == "Work") cardColour = "#06065c";
            else cardColour = "#5c0606";
            <h6>@time.LogType</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {

    List<TimeLog> timeList = new List<TimeLog>();
    TimeLog times = new TimeLog();    
    string cardColour;

    public class TimeLog
    {
        public string LogType { get; set; }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        times = new TimeLog();
        times.LogType = "Work";
        timeList.Add(times);
        times = new TimeLog();
        times.LogType = "Vacation";
        timeList.Add(times);
        times = new TimeLog();
        times.LogType = "Work";
        timeList.Add(times);
        times = new TimeLog();
        times.LogType = "Work";
        timeList.Add(times);
        times = new TimeLog();
        times.LogType = "Vacation";
        timeList.Add(times);
        times = new TimeLog();
        times.LogType = "Work";
        timeList.Add(times);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your div element with the if statement, or just put the if statement before your div. It is skipping it because your if is being evaluated after the cardColour variable is being used. So, it should be throwing off the colour of all your cards by 1.

```
        @if (time.LogType == "Work") cardColour = "#06065c";
        else cardColour = "#5c0606";
<div class="largeCard" id="cardstyle" style="background-color: @cardColour ">
    <div>

        <h6>@time.LogType</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Success! Thank you.